# ggplot plot multi-plot in one page

Tags: ggplot2

How to plot  several subplot in one page? each subplot with it's x,y axis (do not share any axis), but share the legend.
Here is my example data:

```
df <- data.frame(class=paste0('a',1:20),
             x1=runif(20),
             x2=runif(20),
             y1=runif(20),
             y2=runif(20))
```

subplot codes as:

```
p1 <- ggplot(df,aes(x=x1,y=y1))+
  geom_point(aes(color=class),size=2,show.legend=TRUE)+
  stat_smooth(method='lm',color='black')+
  theme_bw()
p2 <- ggplot(df,aes(x=x2,y=y2))+
  geom_point(aes(color=class),size=2,show.legend=TRUE)+
  stat_smooth(method='lm',color='black')+
  theme_bw()
```

I try to plot two graphic x1-y1 and x2-y2, and they share point class.
The plot I expected show as follows:

[image]

Comment: Could you share the code used to produce the above plots? It's otherwise unclear what your intention is except having two subplots.

Comment: @NelsonGon I have update plot that I  expected.

Answer (score 1):

Simply write the following code at the end:

```
grid.arrange(p1,p2,nrow=2)
```

The only problem is that you'd have to content with two legends. You could somehow set `show.legend=FALSE` for `p1` and then tweak its plot margins to make it look like `p2`.

Result with both legends: [image: Two_legend]
Result with legend shown for p2 only: [image: One_legend]

Comment: Yes. It done. It would be perfect that ajusted same plot size except legend.

Comment: the package cowplot can help - look at the get_legend function